# angle detection in fingerprint image with c#

Tags: c#

I have project about fingerprint classification with c# and in one part compute angle.
in this part my project give no answer and hang and dont have any action .
to compute angle first compute sobelx and sobely filter and then compute angle with arctan
please help me

```
// calcute angle***************
public void computeAngle()
{
    sobelx();
    sobely();
    angleIMG = new double[imgsx.Width, imgsx.Height];
    try
    {
        for(int i=10 ; i<=200 ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 10; j <= 150; j++)
            {
                if (Oy(i, j) != 0.0)
                {
                    angleIMG[i, j] = Math.Atan(Ox(i, j) / Oy(i, j)) / 2 + Math.PI / 2;
                    textBox1.Text += Math.Abs(angleIMG[i, j]).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    angleIMG[i, j] = 0.0;
                }
            }
            textBox1.Text = "\n";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);
    }

    //get Ox(i,j)****************
    public double Ox(int i, int j)
    {
        double wx=0.0;
        for (int u = i - 1; u <= i + 1; u++)
        {
            for (int v = i - 1; v <= i + 1; v++)
            {
                Color cw = imgsx.GetPixel(u, v);
                Color cw1 = imgsy.GetPixel(u, v);
                wx =wx+ 2*( cw.R * cw1.R);
            }
        }
        return wx;
    }
    //get Oy(i,j)****************
    public double Oy(int i, int j)
    {
        double wy = 0.0;
        for (int u = i - 1; u <= i + 1; u++)
        {
            for (int v = i - 1; v <= i + 1; v++)
            {
                Color cw=imgsx.GetPixel(u, v);
                Color cw1=imgsy.GetPixel(u, v);
                wy =wy+ Math.Pow (cw.R,2 )- Math.Pow(cw1.R,2);
            }
        }
        return wy;
    }
```

Comment: i mean sobelx filter on the image it is a function that apply on image for construct a Gx and Gy for detect angle

Answer (score 0):

Because Red color can be up to 255, your Ox method can return values up to 1,170,450, and Oy is similar, is this what you intended?
An angle stored as a double will have up to 16 significant figures, and you are trying to concatenate 26,600 of them, this will take a while!  To increase performance, I suggest you round off the angles, for instance to 2 decimal places, and then append them to a StringBuilder, which you can convert back to a string before putting it in your text box.  Do something like 
`sb.Append(angleIMG[i, j].ToString("F2"))`.

Comment: i apply round function on all angle and build string Builder VARIABLE but  donot work correct yet

Comment: sb.Append(angleIMG[u, v].ToString());
                   textBox3.Text = sb.ToString();

Comment: @m, You need to do the sb.Append() within the for loops and the sb.ToString() after the loops.  Also, you are setting the textBox1.Text to "\n" after each j loop, this will replace all your text, you should append this to the existing text instead.